# Generate neighbor (adjacent polygon) grid cell label in 4 sides in QGis Atlas!

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, print-composer, atlas, dynamic-text

I have created a coverage layer in QGis, and i compose the map in print composer and set up the Atlas, everything is ok.

But the only thing i am missing is to do in print composer is to add labels in 4 sides of the current grid cell that shows 4 grid cell neighbor(adjacent polygon) as a text like a dynamic text for example.

Comment: Duplicate of https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/214300/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one option:

1. Create four fields in the atlas coverage layer (something like, "top", "bottom", "left", and "right")
2. Populate each with the appropriate next page value
3. In composer, create for labels and place them on each side
4. For each label in the Item properties>Main properties window define the related coverage field like [% "right" %] or [% "top" %]

These will populate the next page value when exporting out the atlas.