# Generating Multiple Maps Grid by grid

Tags: pyqgis, mapping, atlas

I am new to QGIS and wants to develop a method to generate a series of map in the following case:

I have a polygon feature shapefile of a state and it has multiple polygons inside it of various districts.
I want to divide the whole state into number of overlapping grids and then map them according to the grid.
Here in this image I have highlighted the grid A5. It shows the state polygon along with districts polygons and the grids and its overlap with surrounding grid.
[image: State, polygon and grid]

So there are two possibilities when grids are intersected with polygon: either district polygon will be completely inside the grid (which I want to show as continuous line) or some part of a district polygon will be outside the grid or we can call as overlay polygons (i want to show them as dashed line).

I want to make a map of each grid in a data frame and another data frame showing the whole state polygon and having an extent indicator in it, which will highlight the grid which is mapped on the other data frame. Along with this I want to put a map title which shows the state name and grid no (e.g. Chhattisgarh Grid No A5) likewise in all maps.

I have tried the atlas option but desired results were not obtained.

It would be of great help if this can be done automatically using a python script.

The output map is shown below:

[image: Desired output map]

Comment: Hi there, and welcome to GIS SE! Please be sure to take the [tour], and note the "one and only one" question bit. As it seems your question is mostly focused on the grids, I would suggest dropping the dashed line bit, or making it into a separate post to avoid getting your question flagged.
Could you elaborate on the results of your attempt with the Atlas feature, and why that did not work? With the right expressions and the `@atlas_feature` variable, a lot of what you're describing is possible in an Atlas.

Comment: possible duplicate of https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/214300/how-to-determine-neighbouring-tile-ids-in-qgis ?

Comment: @JoshC while using atlas feature the polygons were overlapping . As you can see in the 1st image the grid A5 consists of 4 small squares who are a part of other grid also so when i am using the atlas option this overlapping of polygon is creating false results. As u can in !st image there are polygon which are on the boundary of A1 and A5 so it should be showed in dashed but it is completely inside B1 grid so it is showing as a continuous line. I hope that i am clear the doubt why atlas option is not working for me.

Comment: I am trying to write a python code for this as i have 100's of state polygon files so it would be an easy task to do it by using python. i want to learn that how to add two data frames of different sizes, then insert multiple polygon files in each data frame, adjust their symbology after that make one data frame as extend indicator of another and then add basic map things such as Title, Scale bar and a text box.