# QGIS Atlas function

Tags: qgis, atlas

I try to make an atlas for a big map.
Is there the possibility to insert a textfield on the diffrent pages of the atlas pages to see wich name the neighbouring pages have?

Comment: does https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/214300/how-to-determine-neighbouring-tile-ids-in-qgis help?

Comment: I ment: What page is south/nord/east/west of the actual one.

Comment: thank you Ian! That is exactly what I was looking for! : )

Comment: ... but the llnk to the script that is offerd there from Germán Carrillo is not working, that would be the thing I would need : [

Answer (score 1):

There are context variables like `@atlas_featureid` that you can use for this purpose. Here an example:

`attribute (get_feature_by_id (@layer, @atlas_featureid-1 ),'NAME')`

You can adapt this to your needs. For a more focused answer, edit your question to add more details.

[image]