# QGIS - page numbers in print layout

Tags: qgis, print-composer, atlas

I use QGIS print layout to create atlas with many features.
I am tring to find a way to show page number left, right, up and down of atlas feature.
Is there any way to insert these page numbers to print layout?

Example is on a picture below. I need to show page number 4, 6, 8 at atlas with page number 5 as is seen at atlas overview.
Unfortunately, script described at post below doesnt work.https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/214300/how-to-determine-neighbouring-tile-ids-in-qgis

[image]

Comment: does https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/214300/how-to-determine-neighbouring-tile-ids-in-qgis answer your question? if not can you add a picture to show us what you are looking for