# Diving Large map into smaller A3 quadrants for surveying

Tags: qgis, printing

I would like a fast way to create smaller maps from a large map that can be printed and given to employees for surveying.
[image: Larger map]
I would like the map to be divided into equal quadrants and then generate a map for each quadrant with its own label.

[image: Zoomed in smaller quadrant]

I am new to using GIS.

Comment: Create a grid with a fitting size, then use the grid to create an atlas. For reference, please check the official documentation.

Comment: Welcome to Geographic Information Systems! Welcome to GIS SE! We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site. Your questions should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that. Please check out our short [tour] for more about how the site works

Comment: does https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/214300/how-to-determine-neighbouring-tile-ids-in-qgis answer your question

Comment: https://docs.qgis.org/3.22/en/docs/training_manual/forestry/forest_maps.html https://www.qgistutorials.com/en/docs/3/automating_map_creation.html

Comment: check this one also https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KgPOwm7GrIo&t=2s