# QGIS - Atlas Settings - Dynamic Text Base on Grid Attributes

Tags: qgis, atlas

I have multiple grids in my project file. I am utilizing Atlas to automatically print all grids. I was successful yet I have added "SEE SHEETS A1..." within the sides of the mapview as required by our client.
What I think now to solve this is similar to Dynamic Text.
Yet I wasn't able to figure it out.

The output is should be like this: [image]

Comment: does https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/214300/determining-neighbouring-tile-ids-in-qgis help?

Comment: Yes, it is a similar thread but it is not directly related to what I need.

Answer (score 3):

This can be done with the `aggregate` function in expressions:

for example the northern neighbour:

```
aggregate(layer:='your_grid_layer',
          aggregate:='concatenate',
          expression:='See sheet ' || "fieldname_with_sheet_nr",
          filter:=intersects($geometry, geometry(@parent))
                  AND x_max($geometry)=x_max(geometry(@parent))
                  AND y_max($geometry)>y_max(geometry(@parent)),
          concatenator:='')
```

Comment: This worked for me very well. It fits what I need. Its just that the prerequisite knowledge is that you know how expressions works in the Layout Manager. Thanks a lot.